# Write Karate for Pagination endpoint

Tags: karate

How to write ***Karate for Pagination*** endpoint ?

```
Scenario: Get Students Pagination - returns 200

    Given path 'student?direction=ASC&isPagination=true'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Error that I am getting

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: status code was: 404, expected: 200, response time: 9, url: http://localhost:8080/studentss%3Fdirection=ASC&isPagination=true&page=0&size=10, response: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1></body></html>
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.status(StepDefs.java:480)
    at ✽.Then status 200(feature/local/Student.feature:49)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karate automatically url encodes the path.

Therefore, use the [param](https://github.com/intuit/karate#param) keyword to add url parameters.

In your case:

```
Scenario: Get Students Pagination - returns 200

    Given path 'student'
    * param direction = 'ASC'
    * param isPagination = 'true'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Be sure to read [path](https://github.com/intuit/karate#path) before building a more complicated path.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not calling the correct url.
Is `http://localhost:8080/studentss%3Fdirection=ASC&isPagination=true&page=0&size=10` returning something else than 404 when you go to this url on your browser?

My guess is there is a problem with `studentss` in your redirected url.

Comment: I have configured `config.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/` for other test classes its working fine. Any other pointers?